# Javascript to display data in matrix format

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a json file in the google drive below that I am trying to pivot using javascript controller and display on html. Problem is data I want to display is not in a tabular format. It should be in a matrix format. PLease help. Thanks in advance.

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1DcYX6souHK0-xjw7P8u4ht0izjCYcoKXfXQ8qU60QE4/edit?usp=sharing

I want my data to be pivoted like below
[image]

Comment: First, I'd say this is not a question. Could you tell us what have you tried so far? What have you investigated? What errors do you have or what output do you have so far?

Comment: So the data is an array of objects and each object has the data for one column, is that correct?